# how can I center button below my text while using bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button below my text (see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/6/ ) and I want to center it, I actually added this line:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to the css code of this button, but it didn't work...
How can I center it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a div with a "text-center" class.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <a href="#about" class="learn-btn animated fadeInUp">Learn more<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/8/

The "text-center" class is bootstrap helper class that has the "text-align: center" property.

See:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment